# Is it possible to bind a command directly to an app bar button?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm creating an MVVM style application for windows phone. With a regular button, you can bind anything that inherits from ICommand to the Command property on a xaml button, like so:

The command property does not seem to exist for buttons in the phones app bar ("shell:ApplicationBarIconButton"). Has anyone figured out how to bind their click event to a Command yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible from the SDK directly, but the AppBarUtils library ( http://nuget.org/packages/AppBarUtils or http://appbarutils.codeplex.com/ ) works nicely.

The codeplex site has example code for different scenarios such as reusing or switching the app bar in a page.

Comment: I don't understand where to add the code in the examples. Should I add it in my page, in the resource, in the application bar? I don't have a complete phone page. I tried everything...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand how to use the chosen solution so I went for another one. You just add the library via nuget. It's [BindableApplicationBar](https://bindableapplicationb.codeplex.com/)

Then you just add the following instead of your normal application bar.

```
<bindableApplicationBar:Bindable.ApplicationBar>
        <bindableApplicationBar:BindableApplicationBar >
            <bindableApplicationBar:BindableApplicationBarButton
                Text="Refresh"
                IconUri="/Images/refresh.png"
                Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" />
        </bindableApplicationBar:BindableApplicationBar>
```

It's just a shame that intellisense doesn't reconize the tags. Otherwise, it works like a charm.